Mutt mail client and set date_format
Can you tell me how to write the setting set date_format in .muttrc to display the date according to this format on today's date the date should be displayed 10/05/2024 .
I wrote set date_format="%d/%m/%Y" - no change.
set date_format="%d/%m/%Y" has not been successful

Where do you want to observe a DD/MM/YYYY format? In the messages listing (index)? In the message (pager)? In the attribution line?
